# Substracting in PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

If I have dataframes like this:

```
df_1 =

metadata_ids
100
101
102
103


df_2 =

metadata_ids    col_1     col_2 
100             3455      3465
101             3455      3435
102             3565      3445
103             3455      3405
104             3455      3455
105             3495      3115
106             3455      3405
107             3455      3405
```

And I want to check whether what is in the first one can be found in the latter one, I do:

```
output_df = df_1.subtract(df_2.select("metadata_ids"))
```

But what if I have instead a df_1 like this:

```
df_1 =
    
    metadata_ids
    100
    101
    102
    103
    100
    101
    102
    103
    104
    105
    106
    104
    105
    106
```

I tried dropping duplicates before perfoming the substract and it didn't work. My desired output would be an empty dataframe.

Comment: what did it output using the second df_1?

Comment: @samkart an empty dataframe, which was expected, but I would like the same for the second version of df_1.

Comment: @samkart Sorry, I got the column containing 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106.

Comment: dropping the duplicates from df_1 and then doing the subtract returns zero rows

Comment: It's my understanding that you should be getting an empty df in all of these cases.  subtract is basically a set operation - that is, already distinct

Comment: Why not do an inner join?

Answer (score 1):

dropping duplicates before the subtract will result in zero rows, as will without dropping.

```py
data1_sdf.dropDuplicates(). \
    subtract(data2_sdf.select('metadata_id').dropDuplicates()). \
    show()

# +-----------+
# |metadata_id|
# +-----------+
# +-----------+
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed it works, I think the problem in my code is that I use this function in a transformation. This transformation writes the output incrementally (so every time it runs, the output is added to the previous output). Sadly I don't have the option to to replace the output every time, so I was thinking maybe there is a way to do that in this function.